# PDO_OCI Semicolon

Tags: sql, oracle, pdo

It seem that when SQL query has semicolon at the end, prepare/execute statements fail. I get  *ORA-00911: invalid character* error. What I would like to know if this is a pdo_oci driver bug? Has anyone encountered this issue before? 
Example:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO($dsn,$db_username,$db_password,$options);
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
try{
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT "object" FROM "statements" WHERE "subject" = ? and "predicate" = ?;';
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $sth->execute(array('http://192.168.1.234/taooracle/tao_ora_dev.rdf#i1386330868934416', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'));    
    while ($row = $sth->fetch()){
        $uri = $row['object'];  
        echo $uri;
    }    

}catch(PDOException $e){
    print $e->getMessage() ."<br />";
    print $e->getLine() ."<br />";
}

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 911 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

It's easy enough to remove the semicolon, but there are more queries like that, and I want if there's a better option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is working as it should. The ending semicolon is not a part of SQL, it's just a marker for programs like sqlplus, mysql or whatever that one statement is finished. So, you shouldn't be using these semicolons in your code.

I know, mysql accepts them, probably because the devs just put that in after answering too many "why doesn't that work?" questions. But the correct way is to remove the semicolons from your code - the fact that mysql accepts them is more of a bug than the fact other databases don't :-)